# Simple cron sleep RANDOM + wget command not working

Tags: cron, wget

I'm trying to run a cron job in the cPanel of my shared hosting server and having some difficulty, despite looking at many threads on stackoverflow. Hopefully this is something easy to fix.

I'd like to execute this script every hour, but have a random amount of minutes delayed after execution. For example, the script would run at:

0:12, 1:53, 2:34, 3:51, 4:51, 5:31, ..., ..., 23:11, a total of 24 times a day.

Here is what I have that doesn't seem to be executing correctly:

`sleep $((RANDOM%30))s && wget -q -O "https://testurl.com/queuetimed/" > /dev/null 2>&1`

However, still not working, I get this error sent to my email:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `]    
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this, finally.

I don't know why this works and what I had did not, cron *shrug*, but the differences were replacing the && with a ; and also adding a single "-" to the O, and changing the double quotes to single quotes, adding the bash -c reference, though this probably doesn't make a big difference, given that it looks like base was already called previously.

```
15  *   *   *   *   bash -c "sleep $((RANDOM\%1800))s" ; wget -q -O- 'https://testurl.com/queuetimed/' > /dev/null 2>&1
```